# Keeping ActiveRecord response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, controller, paper-trail-gem

In my model I have a method like so:

```
  def self.including_versions
    cars = []
    Car.all.each do |c|
      cars << c
      if c.versions
        c.versions.each do |v|
          cars << v.reify
        end
      end
    end
    cars
  end
```

The problem is that I want to use this in a controller which I can do so by calling `Car.all.including_versions` which is fine. However, My controller then goes on to sort and order and chain further ActiveQuery methods on the end. How can I chain extra things onto it or is there a way I can perform the above without using an Array and keeping it an Active Record Response?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to chain further?

Comment: @Deep Because later in my controller I wish to do things like: `@cars.joins(:garage).order('garages.name ASC').order('cars.name ASC')`.  I was thinking about this issue last night and can't think of a way to solve it as my Car versions are not really objects I can run ActiveRecord queries against. Any ideas?